# Laravel how to get the resting result of comparing two tables

Tags: join, laravel

I hope someone could help.

I have two Tables: "Objects", and "AcquiredObjects", in the first one, I have the description of the object and in the second, I have 3 columns: "object", "user" and "acquired", when someone acquire an object, the table inserts the object_id, the user_id, and a "1" in the acquired column.

I did a query that returns all the acquired objects of a single user:

```
public function acquiredByUser($id_user)
    { 
        return $this->with('resource')

             ->join('AcquiredObjects', 
            function($join) use ($id_user)
            {
                $join->on('AcquiredObjects.object_id', '=', 'object.id' )
                ->where('AcquiredObjects.user_id', '=', $id_user );
            })->get();
    }
```

But now I want a query that returns all the objects NOT acquired by the user.

I've been trying a lot of methods, but i just can't do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about changing *'='* by *'!='* in where clause?

Comment: I tried, but Laravel don't accepts '!=', I always get an error :(

Comment: I remember having a similar problem and I solved it using a RAW query.